# Get Value Of Selected Date And Navigate To Next URL

Tags: php

How can I get the value of the calendar date selected, once selected it should navigate to a php page where I use the value of selected date in the php page to run the query, so far the date selected only displays in the textfield.

eg:

1. PHP page - date selected is 2015-08-11
2. Open up URL to another PHP (in same tab)
3. Use date selected for query ($selected_date = $_GET["DATE"])

This is the calendar view code:

```
      function setupCalendars() {
    // Embedded Calendar
    Calendar.setup(
      {
        dateField: 'embeddedDateField',
        parentElement: 'embeddedCalendar'
      }
    )

    // Popup Calendar

  }

  Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { setupCalendars() })
</script>
```

```
<div style="float: center; width: 50%">

    <div id="embeddedExample" style="">
        <div id="embeddedCalendar">
              </div>
              <br />
                  <div id="embeddedDateField" class="dateField">
                    Selected Date...
                  </div>
              <br />
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it is embedded in the another file (date is selected from this file)

```
                <li><a href="#home" class="anchorLink"><i class="icon-calendar scolor"></i> Date </a>

                                <object type="text/html" data="http://<website>/calendarview.html"
                                        style="width:200%; height:310px; margin-right:50%">
                                </object>
            </li>
```

Comment: "so far the date selected only displays in the textfield." Are you saying there's a textbox already on the page somewhere that displays the selected date, or is that also on the same page that has the actual calendar control?

Comment: same page that has the actual calendar

Answer (score 0):

To do that you're going to have to get the selected date from the child page (is it an iFrame?) and send its value to a field in the parent form when the date is selected. There are a number of ways to do this; you may want to try using the `.contents()` method located [here](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). There's a sample provided that traverses links in an iframe. You should be able to do the same with the textbox.